# comparing between two datetimes

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I have to compare datetimes using sql server 2012, that is, I have to see if certain datetimes from mytable1.start_time1 fall within the range of mytable2.start_time2 and mytable2.end_time2. By the datetime I mean the format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, and I can ignore the time.
What I do (and don't succeed) is as follows:

```
Select CUSTOMER_IDENTITY_NUMBER, a.CREATE_DATE, b.CREATE_DATE, b.END_DATE
from [mytable1]a
join [mytable2]b
on a.CUSTOMER_FK=b.CUSTOMER_PK
where cast(a.CREATE_DATE as date) not between cast(b.CREATE_DATE as date) and cast(b.END_DATE as date)
and cast(a.CREATE_DATE as date)<>cast(b.CREATE_DATE as date)
and cast(a.CREATE_DATE as date)<>cast(b.END_DATE as date)
```

Well, it doesn't work - the a.create_date returned does fall between the two other dates. Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a slightly different condition. I don't quite understand
the logical condition you used. Seems you got it incorrect.

```
select CUSTOMER_IDENTITY_NUMBER, a.CREATE_DATE, b.CREATE_DATE, b.END_DATE
from [mytable1]a
join [mytable2]b
on a.CUSTOMER_FK=b.CUSTOMER_PK
where 
cast(a.CREATE_DATE as date) >= cast(b.CREATE_DATE as date)
and
cast(a.CREATE_DATE as date) <= cast(b.END_DATE as date)
```

Comment: Dear Peter, thanks for your suggestion. I didn't explain correctly what I had needed, but you did help me get back on the track, thanks!